# How to get the list of all the images from DAM which are used in pages in AEM

Tags: sql, adobe, aem, aem-6

How can I find the list of all the images from DAM which are used in content pages using AEM query.

We have many images in DAM but not all are getting used on pages. I have tried some basic (Xpath, SQL2) but couldn't suceeded. Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Beinhoff

Answer (score 1):

You can start by taking a look at the `ReferenceSearch`. The `search` function returns the paths where a given asset is used (you can loop the result of a particular query and adding to a list the assets whose `search` is empty). Now, the task is tricky when taking into account that there are assets used directly in the HTML or CSS or brought dynamically via convention, then this `search` will give you most of the referenced assets, but I would be very cautious to think that the non-referenced are not used at all, but it will serve as a starting point. That is, the assets not explicitly referenced can be analyzed and perform a search in the code to reduce the list even more.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/commons/ReferenceSearch.html

Comment: To expand this "old" answer, you also have to take into account the tags, what images match certain tags for dynamic content displayed based on tags. Also, do not forget experience or content fragments that also can reference assets.